# zip file by *.bat, but want keep old folder structure

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip

I have a problem.

I have

```
foo -- ab
    |  |--bx -- bc
    |  |      |_xr    
    |  |--xb
    |
    |--bb -- bc
    |      |- bx -- bc
    |      |- xr
```

I create file **zip_files.bat** inside directory **foo**:

```
IF EXIST ab.zip del /F ab.zip
IF EXIST bb.zip del /F bb.zip
jar -cMf ab.zip ab
jar -cMf bb.zip bb
```

current, I can zip file to **ab.zip**, then unzip **ab.zip**, it like this (it doesn't like original folder structure):

```
ab -- ab -- bc
       |_bx -- bc
       |     |_xr    
       |_xb
```

***I want*** have file **ab.zip**, when unzip file **ab.zip** have:

```
bx -- bc
    |_xr    
xb
```

I also want have file **bb.zip**.

Comment: What tool are you using to unzip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside folder **foo** put file **zip_files.bat** has content:

```
cd ab
jar -cMf ../ab.zip bx xb
cd ..

cd bb
jar -cMf ../bb.zip bc bx xr
cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-C` option:

> `-C dir`: When creating (c) or updating (u) a JAR file, this option temporarily changes the directory while processing files specified by the file operands.

With your current `jar -cMf ab.zip ab` you get a zip file containing the following entries:

```
ab/
ab/xb/
ab/bx/
ab/bx/_xr/
ab/bx/bc/
```

If you use `jar -cMf ab.zip -C ab .`, you get:

```
xb/
bx/
bx/_xr/
bx/bc/
```

Then, check the tool you use to unzip to extract them in the correct folder and not create a sub folder (it seems you extract `ab.zip` into `ab`, creating two `ab folders`).